# Can I retrieve current URI from Prism Xamarin Forms NavigationService?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I am creating iOS and Android apps using Xamarin.Forms. The app is used to complete a specific workflow. As the user completes entries on each page, I persist the entered data to local storage.

I want to also save a URI to restore the Prism navigation service to the current screen. Doing so will allow the user to resume the workflow where they left off even if the phone is reset, the app is closed by the OS, etc.

I haven't found a way to retrieve the current URI. Is this possible? I can create a dictionary to map screen keywords to URIs manually if necessary, but I'm hoping to avoid such a brittle solution. Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar very well with Prism but do you have an access to NavigationStack from it?

Comment: Hi @YuriS, thanks for the consideration. This is now a feature request for Prism at https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1109.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, this is the solution:

```
string currentPage = NavigationService.GetNavigationUriPath();

await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(currentPage);
```

Comment: You told him how to get the URI but the question is in the context that the app was closed. He is going to need something to store state of the current page uri that persists beyond the life cycle of the app. Personally I would use caching and there is a nuget that simplifies this https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/monkey-cache. Then on app start or whatever event you like you can check the cache for state persistence.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. The feature in your answer was introduced due to my question. :-) See https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1109.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to access the current Navigation Stack with Prism's Navigation Service. If this is something you need I would encourage you to open an [issue](https://github.com/prismlibrary/prism/issues) on GitHub.

Note due to the way Navigation works with Xamarin Forms, you must navigate from a specific page. This requirement means that each ViewModel has to have its own instance of the Navigation Service in order to properly Navigate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't think this was currently possible, but wanted confirmation that I hadn't overlooked something. I will create an issue and see how it goes.

Comment: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1109 created. After some initial confusion that led to it being closed, it has been reopened and in the team's todo list. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Hi @TommyBaggett You mention you are able to save and recreate the navigation stack in XF. How do you recreate the stack? Do you actually create each page and push it to the stack? That doesn't look good I think. If you could share more information would be great!

Comment: Hey @DonBox, Prism allows you to assign a URI and it recreates the stack. So for example, I could assign something like "/NavigationPage/Login/CreateAccountStep1/CreatAccountStep2/CreatAccountStep3" and it would take care of it. Unfortunately, there is currently no way to retrieve the URI to save and restore it later.

Check out https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Prism-for-XamarinForms-with-Brian-Lagunas at around the 43 minute mark for a demonstration of this.

Comment: @TommyBaggett Thank you! I will check that.

Comment: Retriev current uri should be able since the following PR https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/1277/commits/0561c2162132b7438830e3f563d0f96ac759c315

Answer (score 0):

It was added in the release v7.0. There is an extension method for INavigationService called "GetNavigationUriPath". Assuming your navigation service is called NavigationService just use:

**var uriPath = NavigationService.GetNavigationUriPath();**

It will give you the current uri path of the current page.

[image]